# Burninate [importance]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[importance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importance) is a pretty [generic term](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). The only recurring meaning currently used by questions is to refer to various weighing algorithms which is too unspecific.

Comment: This tag has no [importance]

Comment: 3 of them are CSS questions that should have used the [`important`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/important) tag instead (that may need burninating as well).

Comment: This tag is definitively of burning [importance]!

Comment: Don't `import [ance]`. Too meta?

Comment: wow. sometimes you wonder who would create such a tag.

Comment: The [importance] of burnination

Comment: Smells like "guys I have a deadline in 1 hour please answer this quick, it is important (to me)".

Comment: I can't even say it, let alone use it.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [Importance Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling)?

Comment: @wflynny as I said, it does: this is the only recurring meaning. Such questions are typically tagged with [tag:montecarlo] as well. Yet, as I said, too, in this form, this is too unspecific.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In my opinion this tag doesn't add any value. You definitely cannot be an expert in [importance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importance).

There were only 13 questions tagged, I removed this tag from all of them. As far as I remember, the tag will be auto-deleted if there are no questions tagged for some time.

Update: this tag has been auto-deleted.

Comment: But you can be an important expert

Comment: @Jojodmo Yes, but unfortunately we can only tag questions, not users :(

Comment: An expert on importance is called manager. Setting priorities. Experts are rare in this field, that's why only 13 questions tagged.

Comment: Besides, project management questions are better suited for Programmers or The Workplace.